# Convert txt file to vector

Tags: r

I have data in the *.txt file like this.

```
rep trt y
1 7 34.55
2 7 65.88
3 7 34.66
1 8 45.66
2 8 34.55
3 8 32.09
1 9 38.99
2 9 33.44
3 9 35.67
```

How to convert into this form.

```
rep=c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3")
trt=c("7","7","7","8","8","8","9","9","9")
y=c("34.55","65.88","34.66","45.66","34.55","32.09","38.99","33.444","35.67")
```

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use `read.table` to read the text file as dataframe. Use `list2env` to create separate vector of each column.

```
df <- read.table('file.txt', header = TRUE)
list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Note that it is not advisable to create multiple vectors in global environment as they become difficult to manage.

---

You can apply `ANOVA` on the dataframe as well directly.

```
df <- read.table('file.txt', header = TRUE)
model = lm(response ~ A + B, df) 
car::Anova(model,type="III")
```

Comment: :D, upvoted as you were 24 secs faster than me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this one gave these results.
rep
 [1]  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
there is a way to add c("")?

Comment: Where do you want to use this? This is already a vector, why do you need additional `c()` ?

Comment: This is what I intended to do, ANOVA Type III.
`
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
A        = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
B        = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x")
response = c( 14,  30,  15,  35,  50,  51,  30,  32,  51,  55,  53,  55)
model = lm(response ~ A + B)
library(car)
Anova(model, type="III")
`
Only in this form of data produces Type III results.

Comment: You can also apply it in a dataframe so you don't need vectors in that form only. Try `df <- data.frame(A, B, response)`,`model = lm(response ~ A + B, df)` and `car::Anova(model,type="III")` works as well. Can you try the updated answer in my post?

Comment: A million thanks to you. Your suggestion works well. But, I'm curious. When I compared the result from your design to SPSS. There is a difference in SS, even a model was Type III.

Comment: Here is the original design that I use in the first place, This one produces the same SS compared to SPSS.
`
#Preparing data
rep<-scan(text="1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3",what="")
rep
dput(rep)
trt<-scan(text="7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9",what="")
trt
dput(trt)
color<-scan(text="34.55 65.88 34.66 45.66 34.55 32.09 38.99 33.44 35.67",what="")
color
dput(color)
##ANOVA
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
rep=dput(rep)
trt=dput(trt)
color=dput(color)
model=lm(color~rep+trt)
library(car)
Anova(model,type="III")
`

Comment: This is why I want to reshape the data from "*.txt" into `rep=c("1","2",...,"3") in the first place. Here, some screenshots with SPSS. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AptnYtPlSZIXkfQLUM99w5C2wsjs-g?e=CE9gJT

Comment: I really have no idea why there is a difference between these two codes. But, this is critical because the results could lead to a different direction when do hypothesis testing. Here some samples. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AptnYtPlSZIXkfQOGhAxURsMj4RurA?e=MIVRCH

Answer (score 2):

After reading the file, we can use `attach`

```
df <- read.table('file.txt', header = TRUE)
attach(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
rep <- df[["rep"]]
trt <- df[["trt"]]
y <- f[["y"]]
```

OR

```
var_names <- colnames(df)

for(i in var_names) {
  assign(i, df[[i]])
}
```

Output:

```
> rep
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
> trt
[1] 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
> y
[1] 34.55 65.88 34.66 45.66 34.55 32.09 38.99 33.44 35.67
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(rep = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), trt = c(7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9), y = c(34.55, 65.88, 34.66, 45.66, 34.55, 
32.09, 38.99, 33.44, 35.67)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```